# If you refresh a Salesforce oganization, what happens to OAuth credentials and refresh token?

Tags: oauth2, sandbox, sandbox-refresh

I refreshed my Salesforce sandbox and my OAuth credentials (refresh token) doesn't work anymore. Is that expected?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected. When you refresh, you are performing two steps. First, you create a new org, and second, you delete the original org. That means that, after the refresh, you are logging in as a different user than you were before, because the original user, that user's sessions, and the entire org is deleted and no longer exists.